# Meaning of "in four days from now"

Tags: time

I said a sentence "I have my exam in 4 days from now" does this mean I have exam on 4th day or under 4 days ?

Comment: The terminology is remarkably imprecise.  Better to say, eg, "I have my exam on Thursday."

Comment: Most people would start counting from the first day following the utterance, so if you said it on Monday, the implication is that the exam would be on Friday. As far as talking about future events is concerned, what research have you done?

Comment: I've removed "Also, please tell the different ways in which future events can be described in English. "  This is too broad, there are many ways to talk about the future.  You should consult a grammar book or website first, and then ask a question if something is unclear.

Comment: The wording is not precise, it is capable of interpretation. If this is an exam you are taking then I suggest you seek clarification of the exam date and not rely on the interpretation of those words. We recently found a shop's Ts&Cs that include *"... cancellation of your order [is allowed] as long as notice of cancellation is received within two calendar days starting with the date your order is placed"*. The shop insisted that the clause meant cancellation is allowed on the day the order is placed or on the next day, but not any later.

Answer (score 1):

"I have my exam in four days" or "I have my exam four days from now" mean that the exam will occur on the fourth day. So if today is Monday, the exam will occur on Friday. However, it sounds wrong to an English speaker to say, "I have my exam in four days from now."

If you want to say that the exam will occur between now and the fourth day (including the fourth day itself), then you would say, "I *will* have my exam *within* four days."

Answer (score 1):

"In four days"/"four days from now" indicates the fourth day after the current day. So one of these being said on Monday would indicate Friday. Nobody would say "something will happen within four days" when only talking about the fourth day, as using the preopsition *within* indicates that something will occur any of the days between today (the first day) and the fourth day. You must use the first examples when indicating a specific day in this form. Even native English speakers get confused, so the best approach is to simply be specific with the day and/or date in formal situations.